# google.script.run is not executing the given function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script

My project is on Google Apps Script. I've been working on writing an html dialogue for a dropdown menu. I was having issues with getting my secondary function to run, and I've whittled down the issue with google.script.run.

When I run function custdialogue, the menu pops up as expected, and I get the alert with the selected value as expected. On my executions tab, I can see each instance of custdialogue that I test, but no executions for logval.

Is this a formatting error?

JS:

```
function custdialogue() {
  const htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Filename')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(150);
  const ui =SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  ui.showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Title');
};

function logval() {
  console.log("value")
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="option-list">Pick an option:</label>
      <select option="option-list" id="option-list">
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
        </select>
        <button id="button" onclick="submitval()">Click</button>
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="close" onclick="closeIt()"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      function submitval(){
        var entry = $(document.getElementById('option-list')).val()
        alert(entry)
        closeIt()
        
      }
      function closeIt(){
        google.script.host.close()
      }
      
      googe.script.run.withSuccessHandler(submitval)
        .logval();
     

    </script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently, I am expecting to see an execution for custdialogue and an execution for logval. Upon opening the execution for logval, I would see that the console logged "Value".

When I run this function, I only see an execution for custdialogue

Comment: Try running your html on a validator

Comment: I've ran it through a validator. Several minor errors were flagged (and fixed), but none seem to have resolved my issue

Comment: But you have not resolved those issues in your code

Comment: I would like to make a comment.   I did not question the logic of your code.  I simply fixed the typo.  Your `<script>` code executed the `google.script.run` when the page loads which executes the callback function `submitval` which immediately executes `closeIt` so the user can't really do anything because the page opens and closes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a typo in your code.

**Replace**

```
googe.script.run.withSuccessHandler(submitval)
        .logval();
```

**With**

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(submitval)
        .logval();
```

**Add**

I've encapsulated your google.script.run in an Immediate Invoked Execution Function and it works.

```
  (function() {
    try {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(submitval).logval();
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  })();
```

**Reference**

- [IIEF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: I've fixed the typo. I'm still having the same issue, though

Comment: I copied your code and it works for me with the minor modification I’ve shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

gs:

```
function custdialogue() {
  const htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2').setWidth(200).setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlDlg, 'Title');
};

function logval(v) {
  Logger.log(v);
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
      <select id="option-list">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="close" onclick="myfunk();">
    <script>
      function myfunk() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {
          google.script.host.close();
        }).logval(document.getElementById("option-list").value);
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, this works! Thank you. I'm trying to understand exactly what the fix is, here. Is the script closing the window, and having successfully done so, running the next program?

Comment: What is the next program?

Comment: After experimenting with this code a little bit, I'm having an issue. This function takes an incredibly long time to load the google.script.run command. I'm having >5 seconds between clicking the button and the text clearing away. Is there an explanation or solution for this?

Comment: It takes a couple of seconds for me.  There could be several reasons for a longer delay including network delays because withSuccessHandler is asynchronous.